# does it have missing word after "up and down"?

Tags: prepositions, american-english, adverbs

Does it have Missing word In the following sentence?

> If I were, would I have shooting pains up and down my left arm?

I consider *up and down* an adverbial, but in this sentence it's more like a preposition...

Answer (score 1):

No missing words.  They are prepositions.  "Up and down my left arm" = in the upper areas of the arm (closer to the shoulder) *and* the lower areas of the same (closer to the wrist).